# Improving Code - Python

Tags: python

This code works but is not as efficent as possible. Can you tell me how to make it more efficent? I belevie there is away to not have so many functions but I have forgotten how. The script is a multi choose quiz. I have defined each question as a new function. Is this the best way to do this?

```
def firstq (): # 1st Question
    global q1list,answer1
    q1list = ["Wellington","Auckland","Motueka","Masterton"]
    q1count = 0
    print ("Question 1")
    print ("From which of the following Towns is the suburb NEWLANDS located?")
    while q1count < 4:
        print (q1count,"  ",q1list[q1count])
        q1count = q1count + 1
    answer1 = int(input("What number answer do you choose?"))
    if answer1 == 0: print ("Correct answer!")
    elif answer1 != 0: print ("Sorry! Incorrect Answer. Better luck with the next Question.")
    print("Next Question below:")
    print(" ")
    print(" ")



def secq (): #Second Question
    global q2list,answer2 # Makes answer2 and q2list avalible anywhere on the page.
    q2list = ["Wellington","Christchurch","Pairoa","Dunedin"] # List of answers to choose from.
    q2count = 0 # defines what the q2 count is. SEE BELOW
    print ("Question 2")# prints "question 2"
    print ("What NZ town is known for L&P?") # Prints the question
    while q2count < 4:
        print (q2count,"  ",q2list[q2count]) # Whilst the number of answers (q2list) is below 4 it will print the next answer.
        q2count = q2count + 1
    answer2 = int(input("What number answer do you choose?")) # asks for answer
    if answer2 == 2: print ("Correct answer!") # If answer is correct, prints "Correct answer"
    elif answer2 != 2: print ("Sorry! Incorrect Answer. Better luck with the next Question.") # If answer is correct, prints "Sorry! Incorrect Answer. Better luck with the next Question."
    print("Next Question below:") # prints "Next Question
    # these provide spacing!
    print(" ")
    print(" ")


def thrq ():
    global q3list,answer3
    q3list = ["Lewis Carroll","J.K. Rowling","Louis Carroll","Other"]
    q3count = 0
    print ("Question 3")
    print ("Who wrote the book Alice In Wonderland?")
    while q3count < 4:
        print (q3count,"  ",q3list[q3count])
        q3count = q3count + 1
    answer3 = int(input("What number answer do you choose?"))
    if answer3 == 0: print ("Correct answer!")
    elif answer3 != 0: print ("Sorry! Incorrect Answer. Better luck with the next Question.")
    print("Next Question below:")
    print(" ")
    print(" ")

def fouq ():
    global q4list,answer4
    q4list = ["WA","DC","WD","WC"]
    q4count = 0
    print ("Question 4")
    print ("What is the abbreviation for Washington?")
    while q4count < 4:
        print (q4count,"  ",q4list[q4count])
        q4count = q4count + 1
    answer4 = int(input("What number answer do you choose?"))    
    if answer4 == 1: print ("Correct answer!")
    elif answer4 != 1: print ("Sorry! Incorrect Answer. Better luck with the next Question.")
    print("Next Question below:")
    print(" ")
    print(" ")

def fivq ():
    global q5list,answer5
    q5list = ["Yes","No, they're found around New Zealand","No","No, they're found around the UK"]
    q5count = 0
    print ("Question 5")
    print ("Are walruses found in the South Pole?")
    while q5count < 4:
        print (q5count,"  ",q5list[q5count])
        q5count = q5count + 1
    answer5 = int(input("What number answer do you choose?"))
    if answer5 == 2: print ("Correct answer!")
    elif answer5 != 2: print ("Sorry! Incorrect Answer. Better luck with the next Question.")
    print("Next Question below:")
    print(" ")
    print(" ")

def sixq ():
    global q6list,answer6
    q6list = ["G.M.","General M's","G Motors","Grand Motors"]
    q6count = 0
    print ("Question 6")
    print ("What is the other name for General Motors?")
    while q6count < 4:
        print (q6count,"  ",q6list[q6count])
        q6count = q6count + 1
    answer6 = int(input("What number answer do you choose?"))    
    if answer6 == 0: print ("Correct answer!")
    elif answer6 != 0: print ("Sorry! Incorrect Answer. Better luck with the next Question.")
    print("Next Question below:")
    print(" ")
    print(" ")

def sevq ():
    global q7list,answer7
    q7list = ["Greece","USA","Egypt","Italy"]
    q7count = 0
    print ("Question 7")
    print ("Which of the following countries were cats most honored in?")
    while q7count < 4:
        print (q7count,"  ",q7list[q7count])
        q7count = q7count + 1
    answer7 = int(input("What number answer do you choose?"))
    if answer7 == 2: print ("Correct answer!")
    elif answer7 != 2: print ("Sorry! Incorrect Answer. Better luck with the next Question.")
    print("Next Question below:")
    print(" ")
    print(" ")

def eigq ():
    global q8list,answer8
    q8list = ["I find","I see","I presume","I am"]
    q8count = 0
    print ("Question 8")
    print ("Complete this phrase-Dr. Livingstone,")
    while q8count < 4:
        print (q8count,"  ",q8list[q8count])
        q8count = q8count + 1
    answer8 = int(input("What number answer do you choose?"))       
    if answer8 == 2: print ("Correct answer!")
    elif answer8 != 2: print ("Sorry! Incorrect Answer. Better luck with the next Question.")

    print(" ")
    print(" ")

def end():
    if answer1 == 0 and answer2 == 2 and answer3 == 0 and answer4 ==1 and answer5 ==2 and answer6 ==0 and answer7 == 2 and answer8 == 2: print("YAY, all questions correct! You have won the 1 million!")
    else: print("Sorry you have some incorrect questions! You have not won any money! :(") # If all answers are correct, this will display YAY, all questions correct! You have won the 1 million! If not it will print Sorry you have some incorrect questions! You have not won any money! :(.


def printorder ():
    # Defines ther order that it will be printed in
    firstq()
    secq()
    thrq()
    fouq()
    fivq()
    sixq()
    sevq()
    eigq()
    end()

name = l" " # while name is blank it will continue
while name != "quit": #While the name is not quit it will continue. If name is quit it will stop.
    print ("The $1,000,000 Quiz! Can you win the 1 Million?")#Prints Welcome Message
    name = input("Lets Get Started! What is your name: ")# asks for name
    if name == "quit": 
       break # if the name is quit it will stop if not....
    printorder()# ....prints printorder
```

Comment: Indentation matters in Python- please preserve your tabs or this code doesn't work.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you really need to improve efficiency here?  This script is mostly i/o bound (waiting on input from the user) and there is a very low upper bounds on the loops in each question (four iterations).

You should focus instead on code quality and re-usability, you won't gain much in performance by optimizing this code (at least this snippet).

Comment: @AustinMarshall I suspect OP really is concerned about refactoring the code rather than computational efficiency as you are quite correct on that account.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a pointer.

Instead of

```
def sixq():
    global q6list, answer6
    ...
```

create a function

```
def question(qlist, qanswer):
    ...
```

and pass in `qlist` and `qanswer` as parameters, much of the code is duplicated and can be eliminated this way. And you also eliminate the use of `global`s at the same time. You can return whatever value(s) you need to the calling code at the end of this function using `return`. (note that Python allows you to return more than one value)

Adjust above as needed, ie if you need to supply another parameter etc. Essentially you want to factor out duplicate code into a *single* function, and provide the necessary parameters for what makes it unique.

***Finally***, using a single function in place of eight, will making *maintaining* your code much easier. If you find a problem with your code, or simply want to change something, you'll only have to correct it in one place, rather than in 8 different functions .. this is a major benefit.

Comment: It would also be good to hold the questions, choices and answers in a list and then use a for loop over them. That makes it easy to add additional questions.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, that's a very good suggestion, agreed!